# What is the correct use of a generic type in the context of a base class

Tags: java, generics

As in the example below, I need to do an operation on an object of type `A` passing a reference to an object of type `B` to the function, but the expression is invalid:

`a.setId(a.getId());`

```
public class Example {
    public static void main() {
        A<?> a = new B();
        useA(a);

        B b = new B();
        useA(b);
        useB(b);
    }

    static void useA(A<? extends A.AId> a) {
        a.setId(a.getId());
    }

    static void useB(B b) {
        b.setId(b.getId());
    }
}

interface A<ID extends A.AId> {
    ID getId();

    void setId(ID id);

    interface AId {
    }
}

class B implements A<B.BId> {
    @Override
    public BId getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(BId id) {
    }

    static class BId implements A.AId {
    }
}
```

What type should the `a` parameter of the `useA` function be for correct assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try it.

```
static <T extends A.AId> void useA(A<T> a) {
    a.setId(a.getId());
}
```

Comment: I did not think about such a solution, but it works !